# How can I get layer's top label in c++?

Tags: c++, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

1)Is it possible get each the layer's top labels (e.g: ip1,ip2,conv1,conv2) in c++?
If my layer is

```
layer {
  name: "relu1_1"
  type: "Input"
  top: "pool1"
  input_param { 
      shape: { 
          dim:1 
          dim: 1 
          dim: 28 
          dim: 28 
          } 
     }
}
```

I want to get the top label which in my case is "**pool1**"

I searched the examples provided, but I couldn't find anything. currently I'm able to get only the layers names and layer type by the following commands,

```
cout << "Layer name:" << "'" << net_->layer_names()[layer_index]<<endl;
cout << "Layer type: " << net_->layers()[layer_index]->type()<<endl;
```

2) Where can I find the tutorials or the examples which explains most used API's for using caffe framework using c++?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`Net`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1Net.html) class in doxygen:

```
const vector< vector< Blob< Dtype > * > > all_ tops = net_->top_vecs();  // get "top" of all layers
Blob<Dtype>* ptop = all_tops[layer_index][0];  // pointer to top blob of layer
```

If you want the layer's name, you can

```
const string layer_name = net_->layer_names()[layer_index];
```

You can access all sorts of names/data using `net_` interface, just read the [doc](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1Net.html)!

Comment: The ptop will give the pointer but I want to access the top names. For example in my case I want to get "pool1" but I am unable to get this from the pointer which is answered above.

Comment: @GaneshMS please see my edit, and **please** read the [docs](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1Net.html).